What is the difference between turns and layers in winding?
In the question shown in the image here I am not sure as to how the terms "layers" and "turns" differ. Am I right in assuming that the number of turns is the number of times a wire is wound in circles and that layers refer to the number of wires involved?
I'm quite sure my assumption is incorrect as it doesn't explain the presence of the 8 coils mentioned in the image.


For a single turn 8 coil 2-layer winding, the pole pitch is calculated as:
Pole pitch = (No. of coils $\times$ 2)/No. of poles = $(8 \times 2)/4 = 4$


I tried Googling "single turn 8 coil 2-layer winding". This came up. Perhaps it will help? https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/coil-winding-how-to-layer-coil-turns.564894/

From this thread I understand that a turn is just one winding of a wire and layering refers to adding a turn over another turn. There's another answer down below that says the same thing so I think this is indeed what it is.

Imagine you are winding a coil onto a cylindrical bobbin. your winding machine "lays" the wire down as you go and for every complete turn of the bobbin, it advances the wire spool by one wire diameter. In this way it produces a perfect, flat, gap-free winding that is one wire diameter thick, and the "pitch" of the wrap is one wire diameter per turn.
Then the machine reverses its wire feed direction and lays a second wrap layer on top of the first in the same way. Same result: a perfect, flat, gap-free winding layer.
This illustrates the difference between layers and turns.
By the way, if you are winding the coil by hand and the turns are all over the place (not in neat, orderly layers) the the coil is said to be "scramble-wound".
